# How to input # of user profiles to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, user-tracking

Website was without analytics for some time and now it has 680 user profiles, 36 business profiles and 27 nonprofit profiles.

What is best practice to input total # of profiles of each category to Google Analytics? 
And to keep track of those numbers changing in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version of Google Analytics you are running, you could use a [Custom Variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) or [Custom Dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) that fires when a user creates a profile.